Place circle as close as possible to point P, but without overlapping other circles
I have a point P, and a bunch of non overlapping circles as well. I want to draw a circle of radius r whose center C is as close as possible to P, but that doesn't overlap any of the existing circles. How do I find C?
If there's a single circle I can check if the circles overlap by comparing the distance between their centers and the sum of their radii. If they overlap, that is to say, the distance between their centers d = sqrt((P.x - Ce.x)**2 + (P.y - Ce.y)**2) is less than the sum of their radii s = r + re, then to find the new position for P I first find a vector from from the center of the first circle to the center of the new one, v = new Vector(P.x - Ce.x, P.y - Ce.y)​, then set the magnitude of this vector to the overlap between the circles, which is the difference between the sum of their radii and the distance between the centers overlap = s - d​, so v.set_mag(overlap)​, and finally I add v to P to find C; C = new Vector(P.x + v.x, P.y + v.y)​.
It certainly works for the case where there's only one circle in the canvas already, for example if there's a circle of radius re = 2 at Ce = { x: 0, y: 0 }​, and I want to put a circle of radius r = 2 at P = { x: 3, y: 0 }​, then this algorithm would give C = { x: 4, y: 0 }, but if there is another circle of radius rf = 2 at Cf = { x: 7, y: 0 } then the new circle would overlap this existing one, and following the algorithm above I'd end up where I started, so I need a better algorithm. If I just keep an array of old moves, and I add them to the new position then in the case above the old move would cancel out with the new one.
